# Backtrace - PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
 here  | there | 
-------+-------+
 {1,1} | {1,1} |
 {1,1} | {2,1} |
 {1,1} | {1,2} |
 {1,2} | {1,3} |         
 {2,1} | {2,2} |         
 {2,1} | {3,1} |         
 {3,1} | {3,2} |         
 {2,2} | {2,3} |          
 {3,2} | {3,3} |
```

I would like to make a Backtrace from `{3,3}` to `{1,1}`. 
I would like to concatenate all points from the Backtrace in an array.

The result would look like this:

```
{1,1},{2,1}{3,1},{3,2},{3,3}
```

How can i manage that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a rather simple recursive query. Use an additional column `depth` to get the expected order of points in the final aggregation.

```
with recursive backtrace(here, there, depth) as (
    select here, there, 0
    from my_table
    where there = '{3,3}'
union all
    select t.here, t.there, b.depth+ 1
    from my_table t
    join backtrace b on b.here = t.there and b.here <> b.there
)

select string_agg(there::text, ',' order by depth desc) as backtrace
from backtrace

           backtrace           
-------------------------------
 {1,1},{2,1},{3,1},{3,2},{3,3}
(1 row)
```